# Batch file command line arguments

Tags: batch-file

It seems an '=' sign on an argument splits that argument into two. ie. if I have a batch file a.bat:

```
echo %1
echo %2
```

and call it using:

```
a 1=2
```

it will give as a result:

```
1
2
```

whereas I want it to give:

1=2 for the first argument.

If I put quotes around "1=2" it works however it keeps the quotes in %1.

Any idea how to get 1=2 into %1 ?

Comment: well half my comments disappeared below, why is that?

Comment: because they were comments to a now deleted answer.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the surrounding quotes from an argument, include a `~`.

```
echo %~1
```

Comment: the argument doesn't have quotes: argument 1 is 1=2, I want that to go into %1

Comment: Yes, if you put "1=2" in quotes, it will work. The `~` will then remove the quotes so that `%1` will hold the value `1=2` and not `"1=2"`.

Comment: No you're missing the point, the user will not call the batch file with quotes, the user will call it with 1=2.  It is my job in the batch file to interpret that correctly.

Comment: @Arthur, you never said the user would not call the batch files without quotes.  You cannot override the default delimiters that cmd.exe uses unless you put your arguments in quotes.

Comment: @squashman I did, in my post I said "Any idea how to get 1=2 into %1 ?"

Comment: Use `%*` instead of `%1`

Comment: @Arthur - Well then tell the user to put the argument in quotes and when they don't, mock them for their inability to read your very clear instructions that you gave them initially.

Comment: wow @Aacini %* works!  dos batch language - the land of undocumented features

Comment: @Arthur It **is** documented, just read `call /?` or http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html